# python3 Can't import dbus even though it's installed

Tags: python, python-3.6

I'm trying to use dbus in a python3 project, but when I try to import it, I get an error:

```
>>> import dbus
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dbus'
```

So I tried to fix it by making sure dbus is installed for my python 3.6 installation but it seems to already be installed:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-dbus
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-dbus is already the newest version (1.2.0-3).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I'm able to import dbus in python 2.7 without any problems, but my python3 can't seem to find the module even though it shows that it's already installed. My `which python3` shows it's installed in /usr/local/bin/python3

Comment: did you find any solution for this?

Comment: I forget exactly how I got it to work but I believe I copied dbus from dist packages to where python libraries are installed through pip. I think it was just not installed in the correct place although this could be incorrect as I fixed this so long ago.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, that works for me.

Comment: If you’d like to and have the time, it could be helpful to answer the question with the specific steps you took to correct this issue!

Comment: I haven't yet got it working the way I want it to...

Answer (score 1):

You are probably getting this error because the path to the module installed by `apt-get` is not in your `sys.path`. One solution you can try is this:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages")
import dbus
```

Comment: I think the installation must have gotten messed up because after adding the path, importing dbus gives me this error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_dbus_bindings'. I've reinstalled dbus through apt but that didn't help. On another note, you should probably edit your post to start the path at / though in case this  method helps someone else later.

Comment: Are you running your script in Python 3? You would get that error if your script is being ran in Python 2.x. Try `python3 script.py`

Comment: Yes, I'm sure I'm running python3. I don't know why I'm getting that error now.

Comment: I'm having this issue installing Nvidia drivers on ubuntu 16.04, same problem. If you give it the `dist-packages` path, the error moves to `no module named _dbus_bindings`.